# Angular FileUploader - has URL with undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, xmlhttprequest

I have a following controller:

```
controllersAdmin.controller( 'productCreate' , [ '$scope' , '$http' , '$timeout', 'checkToken', 'categoriesService', 'FileUploader', function( $scope , $http, $timeout, checkToken, categoriesService, FileUploader ){

$scope.product = {};

// get products
$http.post( 'api/admin/products/get', {

    token: checkToken.raw()

}).then( function( data ){

    $scope.products = data.data;

    if($scope.products.length > 0) {
        $scope.product['id'] = Number($scope.products[$scope.products.length-1].id)+1;
    } else {
        $scope.product['id'] = 1;
    }

}, ( function(){

    console.log( 'Error on communicate with API.' );

}));

// init uploader
var uploader = $scope.uploader = new FileUploader({

    token: checkToken.raw(),
    url: 'api/admin/images/upload/' + $scope.product['id']

});
```

In a template controlled by this controller i have following:

```
<h3>Upload product photo</h3>

            <div ng-show="uploader.isHTML5">
                <!-- 3. nv-file-over uploader="link" over-class="className" -->
                <div class="well my-drop-zone" nv-file-over="" uploader="uploader">
                    Drag & drop photo here
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Example: nv-file-select="" uploader="{Object}" options="{Object}" filters="{String}" -->
            <input class="btn btn-default" type="file" nv-file-select="" uploader="uploader" multiple  /><br/>

            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="50%">Name</th>
                    <th ng-show="uploader.isHTML5">Size</th>
                    <th ng-show="uploader.isHTML5">Progress</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="item in uploader.queue">
                    <td>
                        <strong>{{ item.file.name }}</strong>
                        <!-- Image preview -->
                        <!--auto height-->
                        <!--<div ng-thumb="{ file: item.file, width: 100 }"></div>-->
                        <!--auto width-->
                        <div ng-show="uploader.isHTML5" ng-thumb="{ file: item._file, height: 100 }"></div>
                        <!--fixed width and height -->
                        <!--<div ng-thumb="{ file: item.file, width: 100, height: 100 }"></div>-->
                    </td>
                    <td ng-show="uploader.isHTML5" nowrap>{{ item.file.size/1024/1024|number:2 }} MB</td>
                    <td ng-show="uploader.isHTML5">
                        <div class="progress" style="margin-bottom: 0;">
                            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" ng-style="{ 'width': item.progress + '%' }"></div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-center">
                        <span ng-show="item.isSuccess"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span>
                        <span ng-show="item.isCancel"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i></span>
                        <span ng-show="item.isError"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></span>
                    </td>
                    <td nowrap>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" ng-click="item.upload()" ng-disabled="item.isReady || item.isUploading || item.isSuccess">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span> Upload
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" ng-click="item.cancel()" ng-disabled="!item.isUploading">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></span> Cancel
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" ng-click="item.remove()">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Remove
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <div>
                <div>
                    Queue progress:
                    <div class="progress" style="">
                        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" ng-style="{ 'width': uploader.progress + '%' }"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-s" ng-click="uploader.uploadAll()" ng-disabled="!uploader.getNotUploadedItems().length">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span> Upload all
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-s" ng-click="uploader.cancelAll()" ng-disabled="!uploader.isUploading">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></span> Cancel all
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-s" ng-click="uploader.clearQueue()" ng-disabled="!uploader.queue.length">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Remove all
                </button>
            </div>
```

First I am getting data by `$http.post` from my API.

Then I initialize file uploader based on `$scope.product['id']`, however it shows me URL: `api/admin/images/upload/undefined` so `$scope.product['id']` is **undefined** outside `$http.post`.

How do I access this variable after getting data from `$http`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$http.post` method returns a promise because it is an asynchronous action.

Because of that you are initialization the uploader before the function inside the `then` is executed, so `$scope.product['id']` still has an undefined value.

Try to initialize the uploader (`$scope.uploader`) inside the on fulfill function of the promise.

**E.g:**

```
$http.post( 'api/admin/products/get', {

    token: checkToken.raw()

}).then( function( data ){

    $scope.products = data.data;

    if($scope.products.length > 0) {
        $scope.product['id'] = Number($scope.products[$scope.products.length-1].id)+1;
    } else {
        $scope.product['id'] = 1;
    }
    var uploader = $scope.uploader = new FileUploader({
        token: checkToken.raw(),
        url: 'api/admin/images/upload/' + $scope.product['id']

});

}, (function(){

    console.log( 'Error on communicate with API.' );

}));
```

To avoid getting an error because `$scope.uploader` is not yet defined (it's creation is delayed by the http call) you can use `ng-if="uploader !== undefined"` before using the upload directive.

Comment: I tried that but it gives me an error:

"TypeError: "Uploader" must be an instance of FileUploader"

I have added injection "FileUploader":
controllersAdmin.controller( 'productCreate' , [ '$scope' , '$http' , '$timeout', 'checkToken', 'categoriesService', 'FileUploader', function( $scope , $http, $timeout, checkToken, categoriesService, FileUploader ){

Comment: Can you edit the question with a link to where you got this `FileUploader` service, And show some code of how you are using it? I can't help you with the amount of information you are presenting.

Comment: In a template controlled by this controller i have following code:
https://pastebin.com/sT9mqa0h

Comment: Please try to put the relevant code in the question instead of dumping it all to pastebin. I think your problem can be solved by simply putting `ng-if="uploader !== undefined"` before you use it.

Comment: I found the [module](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/wiki/Module-API) you are using for the upload. You should include that in the question, because you are not following it's [documentation](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/wiki/Module-API) correctly

Comment: So please don't forget to accept the answer, it means a lot to me.